# How to access programatically created UI object from a calss member function

Tags: ios, swift

I created a text view programatically and I have an external function outside viewdidload within which I want to change the contents of that textview.  How do I achieve that?  Here's the code I'm working with
As things stand. I'm currently getting this error "Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'textView' " on the line
self.view.textView.text = "Yo Dawg!!"

```
class rootViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         let myTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,50))
         myTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
         myTextView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         myTextView.font = UIFont (name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 20)
         myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
         myTextView.text = "Hello World"

         self.view.addSubview(timerView)

    }//End view did load



    func changeText(){//This function updates the text within the textview
        self.view.textView.text = "Yo Dawg!!"
   }//End change text function

}//End rootViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to your text view in an instance variable/property, not in a local variable:

```
class rootViewController: UIViewController {

    var myTextView:UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         self.myTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,50))
         self.myTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
         self.myTextView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         self.myTextView.font = UIFont (name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 20)
         self.myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
         self.myTextView.text = "Hello World"

         self.view.addSubview(timerView)

    }//End view did load



    func changeText(){//This function updates the text within the textview
        self.myTextView.text = "Yo Dawg!!"
   }//End change text function

}
```

Comment: Paulw11 I understand your reasoning but this doesn't work.  I get this error "member of type rootViewController has no member myTextView"   The solution provided by Seto above however, works

Comment: IIRC, you don't need to call variable using `self.` anymore in swift. So instead of call `self.myTextView.text = ` you could simply write `myTextView.text = `.

Comment: You don't have to, but as a long-time OOP programmer I like to use the convention in order to make it clear when you are working with a local variable and when you are working with a property, particularly when you may inadvertently have a property and local variable with the same name

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an unique tag to the textview and use it to get the reference.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let myTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,50))
     myTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
     myTextView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
     myTextView.font = UIFont (name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 20)
     myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
     myTextView.text = "Hello World"

     myTextView.tag = 1

     self.view.addSubview(timerView)
}



func changeText(){
    if let myTextView = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextView {
        myTextView.text = "Yo Dawg!!"
    }
}
```